# SQL Server - copy data and transformation in a small time window

Tags: .net, sql-server, architecture, ssis, etl

We have a SQL Server 2008 database. The database needs to copy data from 3 separate servers. Once data is copied, we do data transformation (de-normalize etc.)

The data is copied using SSIS packages running in a small nightly window(3 hours). For example:

- Job A runs between 1-2
- Job B 2-3
- Job 4 2-3

This is causing a few issues:

- As data is growing, Job A cannot finish by 2, Job B kicks off and fails
- On some days, jobs run outside of maintenance window
- Each data copy job creates a few other SQL jobs
- The resultant SQL jobs are clashing which results in error

One way I am thinking to fix this is - by having separate staging database, which will copy data all day, then setup SQL replication to production database.

We also need a queuing system so that jobs can have priority, dependencies etc because some jobs are sequential and some can run in parallel.

Is there a any other better way to solve this problem? Any help on our options would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may want to implement some sort of Agent Chaining - http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3605/chaining-sql-server-agent-jobs

Comment: I agree with OnoSendai. And to make the jobs faster - if Server Cores permit - use Parallelism when possible: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd795221(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post more info about this statement?

"As data is growing, Job A cannot finish by 2, Job B kicks off and fails".

A detailed listing of your error messages will be helpful. What I am wondering is this...

1) Is your error due to hardware resource constraints?

or

2) Can it be solved by adding [Precedence Constraints](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141261.aspx) to your packages in SSIS?

or

3) Are both happening?

If I assume for a moment that part of the issue at least can be solved by adding Precedence Constraints in your SSIS packages, often the situation one runs into is this:

I have several packages that run fine on their own as is when run individually. However, when run together they don't play nicely with each other. What is more I really am not in the mood nor do I have the time I would need to redesign/refactor these several packages as one large package with the needed precedence constraints.

When that happens, this solution presents itself:

1. Create a new "Parent" package
2. Add [Execute Package tasks](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137609.aspx) to the Parent package to call your child packages
3. Using Precedence Constraints, constrain each child package to run with as many or as few degrees of parallelism as your hardware resources allow and data model demands

This Parent package would have **no data flow tasks** in it. Rather its only purpose is to manage **control flow logic**. If this gives you the performance you need and is not used simply as a work around for package refactoring that really needs to be done, it is a viable option. For sure it is a matter of trial and error to get it "right".

In general, I would say that I prefer the control flow themed Parent package over complex SQL Server Agent jobs because I feel that SSIS is simpler to configure, gives your more flexibility, and this approach allows you to encapsulate your ETL logic in SSIS as opposed to spreading it out over SSIS and SQL Server Agent. For many of my ETL tasks, my usage of SQL Server Agent has boiled down to scheduling and one simple step that calls a control flow themed Parent package.

I would say that the use of separate staging tables as a way to solve the problem is also worth investigating. That is more of a data model thing best left up to you the data model expert. That approach can help if your current data model does not allow packages to run in parallel (several processes insert data via bulk insert to the same table at the same time for example). However, the multiple staging tables solution is not a great option if the root issue for performance is a hardware resource constraint.

I would guess in the end to find optimal performance you probably end up using a mix of both these solutions and maybe request additional hardware resources for your ETL.

Hard to know what to recomend without more details in your question. Hope this helps.